# GCS Signed URL Post Object using XMLHttpRequest with progress listener results in browser sending Options instead of POST

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have successfully implemented upload of an Object using multi-part Post request with Signature, Policy document [GCS POST](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object)  ...etc from the browser using XMLHttpRequest and angular `$http` .

But when I attach event listener on XMLHttpRequest upload to show a progress bar to the user, the browser sends a Options Method instead of POST. storage.googleapis.com returns 200 ok After that I was expecting a POST to be sent from the browser with the file but that did not happen. Without the upload listener the code works perfectly. Should I move to PUT ? any workaround

```html
   factory.uploadFileToUrlXHR = function(file,obj){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append('key', obj.key);
         fd.append('Content-Type',obj.contenttype)
         fd.append('GoogleAccessId', obj.googleaccessId);
         fd.append('policy', obj.policy);
         fd.append('signature', obj.signature);
         fd.append('file', file);
         var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
         XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
           //  alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
             deferred.resolve(event);
         });

       XHR.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(evt){
              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                 $log.info("add upload event-listener" + evt.loaded + "/" + evt.total);
               }
            }, false);

  // Define what happens in case of error
        XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
          //alert('Oups! Something went wrong.');
          deferred.resolve(event);
         });

  // Set up our request
        XHR.open('POST', obj.uri);

  // Send our FormData object; HTTP headers are set automatically
        XHR.send(fd);
         return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue ,

When you use POST from the browser to upload a file to Google Cloud storage  append the bucket name to the URL . In the below code obj.uri should be "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname

XHR.open('POST', obj.uri); and remove the bucket name from the key. Key should contain the object name.

fd.append('key', obj.key);

if you do not append the bucket name as part of the POST URL, the browser will send the Options request to https://storage.googleapis.com/. GCS will not be able to find the right CORS configuration. CORS configuration is mapped to the bucket Name.

Sample CORS configuration i had applied.

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8282"],
      "method": ["OPTIONS","PUT","POST","GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```